# Filtering Angular 17

Tags: javascript, angular, filtering

I'm currently coding an Angular 17 app and I am having trouble with filtering. The problem I am having is whenever I select a category to filter the data the filter logic excludes all data. Not sure why exactly but nothing I try seems to fix it.

Filter.component.ts

```
import { Component,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent {
  @Output() filterApplied: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  categories = {
    Document: false,
    DocumentSection: false,
    Playbook: false,
    Project: false,
    Conclusion: false,
    Op: false,
    Plan: false,
    // Add more categories here
  };

  sortBy: string = 'title';

   // Function to handle filtering logic
    applyFilters(type= " ") {
    // Implement filtering logic based on selected categories, types, and sorting option
    this.filterApplied.emit({categories: type, sortBy:this.sortBy});
  }
}
```

Filter.component.html

```
<section class="filter">
    <h3>Filter Templates</h3>
    <div class="sort-by">
        <h3>Sort By</h3>
        <select>
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="created_by">Created By</option>
        <option value="mostPopular">Most Popular</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-category">
        <h3>Filter by Category</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox"(click)="applyFilters('document')"> Document</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"(click)="applyFilters('documentSection')"> Document Section</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"(click)="applyFilters('playbook')"> Playbook</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" (click)="applyFilters('project')"> Project</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"(click)="applyFilters('conclusion')"> Conclusion</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"(click)="applyFilters('op')"> Op</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"(click)="applyFilters('plan')"> Plan</label>
    </div>
</section>
```

FilterData Logic

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TemplateComponent } from '../template-market/template-market.component';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { Templates} from '../../templates';
import { TemplateService } from '../../Services/template.service';
import { FilterComponent } from '../filter/filter.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    standalone: true,
    imports:[
        CommonModule,
        TemplateComponent,
        FilterComponent
    ],
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrl:'./home.component.css'
})

export class HomeComponent{
    templateList: Templates[] =[];
    filteredTemplateList: Templates[] =[];
    templateService: TemplateService = inject(TemplateService);
    filteredCategories:any;
    filteredSortBy!:string;

    constructor(){
        this.templateService.getAllTemplates().then((templateList: Templates[])=>{
            this.templateList = templateList;
            this.filteredTemplateList = templateList;
        });
    }

    applyFilter(event:any){
        console.log('Selected categories:', event.categories); 
        this.filteredCategories = event.categories;
        this.filteredSortBy = event.sortBy;
        this.filterData();
    }

    filterData() {
        // Create a copy of the original templateList to avoid modifying it directly
        this.filteredTemplateList = [...this.templateList];
    
        // Filter based on selected categories
        this.filteredTemplateList = this.filteredTemplateList.filter(Template => {
            // Check if the template belongs to any selected category
            for (const category in this.filteredCategories) {
                if (this.filteredCategories[category] && Template.template_type.includes(category)) {
                    console.log('Matched template:', Template);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false; // Exclude the template if it doesn't belong to any selected category
        });
    
        // Sort the filtered list based on selected sorting option
        switch (this.filteredSortBy) {
            case 'title':
                this.filteredTemplateList.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
                break;
            case 'created_by':
                this.filteredTemplateList.sort((a, b) => a.created_by.name.localeCompare(b.created_by.name));
                break;
            case 'mostPopular':
                // You need to implement logic to sort by popularity (e.g., review count & rating)
                break;
            default:
                // Default sorting option, no sorting needed
                break;
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Could you please update your code in the stackblitz URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zd1xp1?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Also could you please explain more. What exactly you want to achieve it ?

Comment: I need to filter the templates bases on a selected category. So if i select for example project category i only need to see all templates with template_type: project

Comment: So I manage to see what was happening and fixed it thank you for your help, I just have one other question how could i manage to get it to show all if no category is selected, or how can i get it show all if unchecking a category  @Ｒの卄ＩＴ

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Could you please update your code on the StackBlitz URL that i shared with you already? You can update your code there and then will check

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ ok i will update stackblitz, i kinda moved on with other things as well so all of that will be in there as well.

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ stackblitz updated and i added some more files that i am working on search bar, favorites

Comment: Could you please share the updated StackBlitz URL? Where have you added more files, and also tell me what is left to do so ?

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ I am having trouble with the search functionality in the console its working but not displaying on the ui https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nw4un3?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.html

Comment: What you want to display—could you please add that to the snippet? I don't understand. Do you want to filter some of the content based on the categories or something else? It would be great you could add mock data in the StackBlitz code

Comment: I want when you type in the search bar the list shows all items with the works you search for or close to it

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴi added a db.json file https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nw4un3?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Fdb.json

Comment: Where is the search bar? Do you have the code for that? db.json  should be used on the UI. like Flipkart, which basically shows all of the items. Could you please add that code as well?

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ i added the files the search bar is in app.component.html https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nw4un3?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Ftemplate-market%2Ftemplate-market.component.ts